# Clearing raster layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, erase

I have TIFF raster layers in QGIS project. I need to 'erase' them ( like in MS Paint ), clean them of any smudges from low scan. I do not see a proper 'eraser' tool like that in QGIS. How can I remove unwanted contaminations of layer?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Serval plugin lets you modify the values of a raster, pixel by pixel. It would be too artisanal work to modify them all. I don't know if there is another plugin to make QGIS work as an image modification tool in that way. A workaround that I can think of would be to draw polygons in the areas to be erased, rasterize them and then perform an algebra operation between the rasters. Are you sure you want to use QGIS for that task?

Comment: I think it would be much faster to do this in a classic image manipulation software like GIMP or Photoshop and than georefence the cleared images again.

Comment: What image manipulation software would be best for this work - Paint.Net, GIMP or Inkscape? What does georefence mean?

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/georeferencing_basics.html